# Plotting a hexagonal histogram

Tags: plotting, complex, visualization, histograms, lattices

For positive integers $D$, I have a function `s[D_]` which creates a list of complex numbers, all of the form $a+b\sqrt{-D}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers. These numbers have a lattice structure which, unless $D=1$, is not square.

I want to understand how `s[D_]` is distributed for various $D$, so a 3D histogram is the best way to do this. But, the usual `Histogram3D` is not very useful because of how the sampling works out with the distribution of the points.

**What I'm trying to do:** I want to make a 'hexagonal histogram' which:

1. For each integer pair $(a,b)$ with $|a|,|b|\leq N$, counts how many times $a+b\sqrt{-D}$ appears in `s[D_]`. (The input variables are $N$ and $D$.)
2. Generates a 3D graph where, at each complex number $a+b\sqrt{-D}$, there is a vertical bar whose height corresponds to the number of times $a+b\sqrt{D}$ appears in `s[D_]`.

This is *almost* what the normal Histogram function does, but it checks for values in square subregions of the plane, which is not optimal when my set exists in a non-square lattice.

**Optional (but would be very neat):** Unfortunately, if rectangular bars are constructed at the lattice vertices, they usually won't fill the space in between them. However, if these bars are more generally look like extruded regular $k$-gons where $k$ depends on $D$, then the resulting histogram will tile the space completely. I can figure out that `k[D_] := 2*Pi / Arg[Sqrt[-D]]`, but I have no idea how to make Mathematica change the form of the graph's bars.

Comment: how about `ListPointPlot3D[
 Append[#, Count[s[d], #[[1]] + #[[2]] Sqrt[-d]]] & /@ 
  Tuples[Range[n], 2], Filling -> Bottom]`?

Comment: or `DiscretePlot3D[Count[s[d], a + b Sqrt[-d]], {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}, 
 ExtentSize -> Full]`?

Comment: Have you looked at [`ResourceFunction["HextileBins"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HextileBins) ?

Comment: @flinty I have not, didn't know about it. I'm not sure how to turn those into objects in a plot but I'll try it out when my dataset is finished generating.

Comment: @kglr I will try those when my dataset has finished generating, thank you.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to turn those into objects in a plot [...]" -- see the "Applications" sub-section in [`HextileBins`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HextileBins).

Answer (score 3):

You can (ab)use the fact that a hexagonal grid can be transformed into a grid with right angles and back. This allows you to use [`DiscretePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot3D.html) with a custom [`ExtentElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExtentElementFunction.html) to get the hexagonal cells on a grid with right angles, which you can then transform into the hexagonal grid:

The transform to go from hexagonal grid -> right angle grid:

```
transform = 
 ScalingTransform[{1, 2/Sqrt[3], 1}]@*
  ShearingTransform[π/6, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}]
```

The function to generate the hexagonal cells: (note that the hexagon generated by `CirclePoints` is transformed using `transform` to make it fit onto the right-angle grid)

```
hex[{{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}, {z1_, z2_}}, ___] :=
 Polygon@Join[
     # (bottom and top faces),
     MapThread[Join[#, Reverse@#2] &, Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, 1}] & /@ #] (* 6 side faces *)
     ] &[(* generate the two bottom and top faces *)
  (# {x1, y1, 1} + (1 - #) {x2, y2, 0} & /@ 
      transform[
       Append[#] /@ (0.5 + 
          CirclePoints[{0.5/Cos[π/6], π/6}, 6])]) & /@ {z1, z2}
  ]
```

An example plot now looks like this from the top:

```
DiscretePlot3D[
 PDF[MultivariatePoissonDistribution[3, {1, 1}], {t, u}], {t, 0, 
  10}, {u, 0, 10},
 ExtentSize -> Full,
 ExtentElementFunction -> hex,
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]},
 PlotStyle -> EdgeForm@Black
 ]
```

[image]

Applying the inverse of `transform` to the result gives you the undistorted grid:

```
DiscretePlot3D[
  PDF[MultivariatePoissonDistribution[3, {1, 1}], {t, u}], {t, 0, 
   10}, {u, 0, 10},
  ExtentSize -> Full,
  ExtentElementFunction -> hex,
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]},
  PlotStyle -> EdgeForm@Black
  ] // MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, InverseFunction@transform] &, 
  1]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `ChartElementFunction` for Histogram3D?

This is not the solution but just a pointer:

```
renderer[c : {{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}, {z0_, z1_}}, data_, meta_] := 
 Print[c]
```

For example:

```
cuboid[c : {{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}, {z0_, z1_}}, data_, meta_] := 
 Cuboid @@ Transpose@c
Histogram3D[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}], ChartElementFunction -> cuboid]
```

Combining with a customized binning function, I think this might be enough of information you will need to create a hexagonal histogram.